# Docker compose replicas with unique host

Tags: docker, docker-compose

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:3.10 AS BASE

RUN apt-get update -y
RUN apt-get install -y iputils-ping

CMD sleep infinity
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  pinger:
    container_name: pinger
    build:
      context: .

  rabbit:
    image: rabbitmq:3.7.7
    #hostname: "rabbit-{{.Task.Slot}}"
    #hostname: "rabbit-{{.Task.ID}}"
    #hostname: "rabbit-{{.Node.Hostname}}"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2
```

run command :
 `docker-compose up`

I want to be able to address each of the rbbitmq replicas separately.
i.e. from the pinger container's shell be able to do

```
ping rabbit-1
ping rabbit-2
```

doing `ping rabbitmq` chooses one of them at random.
you can see my attempts to set `hostname` in the comments.
in all of them, the rabbitmq container fails, as it tries to set the node as `rabbit-{{`

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve?  Taking containers away, the workflow you describe – running a no-op `sleep` command, "going inside" it with a debugging tool, then sending ICMP network debug packets to a message broker – doesn't really make sense.  Is this about connectivity from an application, or setting the per-container `hostname:` so the RabbitMQ (Mnesia) persistence works correctly?

Comment: @DavidMaze my goal is to have two instances of rabbitmq, that I can address separately, the sleep is so the container won't close so I will be able to enter the terminal from the docker desktop to make ```ping``` command to check if the host ```rabbit-<id>``` is something i can use or not